# Perform Macro-Blocking detection within given x, y coordinates using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video-processing

I am trying to develop a script which will detect pixelation from LiveTV from an external camera. To test my script I have been using a short snippet of LiveTV which has two instances of pixelation.

See Google Drive below for video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f339HJSWKhyPr1y5sf9tWW4vcXgBOVbz/view?usp=sharing

Currently I am able to filter out most of the noise in the video, and detect the pixelation. However, I am also detecting the white text (given the intensity of the text it gets picked up by the kernel I am applying).

See the code below:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("./hgtv_short.ts")

while True:
    success, image = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=image, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    sharpen_kernel = np.array([[.4, .4], [-2.25, -2.25], [.4, .4]])
    sharpen = cv2.filter2D(src=gray, ddepth=-1, kernel=sharpen_kernel)
    sharpe = sharpen + 128

    canny = cv2.Canny(image=sharpe, threshold1=245, threshold2=255, edges=1, apertureSize=3, L2gradient=True)
    white = np.where(canny != [0])
    coordinates = zip(white[1], white[0])
    for p in coordinates:
        cv2.circle(canny, p, 30, (200, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.imshow('edges', canny)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

What I would like to do is apply a threshold and findContours to the given coordinates to see if text is in the region. Then I can discern between actual pixelation and text.

**NOTE:**
**If anyone has any other ideas on finding pixelation I am open to suggestions.**

**UPDATE**
Here is a screenshot from the video showing the type of pixelation I am looking for in this video (macro-blocking) to be specific.

Image
[image]

Edges
[image]

From the above Images you can see that I am detecting the macro-blocking, but also the white text. I would like to be able to discern between text and actual macro-blocking.

**SECOND UPDATE**
After more trial and error, I found that it will be best to use some sort of reference model to help predict when an image is showing macro-blocking, pixelation, artifacts, etc...

I have decided to use the hog(Histogram of Oriented Gradients) descriptor to create my feature vector. I have created to functions, one loops through the GOOD images and the other the BAD images:

```
    def pos_train_set(self):
        print("Starting to Gather Positive Photos")
        for pos_file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(self.base_path, "Bad_Images", "*.jpg")):
            pos_img = cv2.imread(pos_file, 1)
            pos_img = cv2.resize(pos_img, self.winSize, interpolation=cv2.CV_32F)
            pos_des = self.hog.compute(pos_img)
            pos_des = cv2.normalize(pos_des, None)
            self.labels.append(1)
            self.training_data.append(pos_des)
        print("Gathered Positive Photos")

    def neg_train_set(self):
        print("Starting to Gather Negative Photos")
        for neg_file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(self.base_path, "Good_Images", "*.jpg")):
            neg_img = cv2.imread(neg_file, 1)
            neg_img = cv2.resize(neg_img, self.winSize, interpolation=cv2.CV_32F)
            neg_des = self.hog.compute(neg_img)
            neg_des = cv2.normalize(neg_des, None)
            self.labels.append(0)
            self.training_data.append(neg_des)
        print("Gathered Negative Photos")
```

I then train my model using the SVM(Support Vector Machines) classification algorithm.

```
    def train_set(self):
        print("Starting to Convert")
        td = np.float32(self.training_data)
        lab = np.array(self.labels)

        print("Converted List")
        print("Starting Shuffle")
        rand = np.random.RandomState(10)
        shuffle = rand.permutation(len(td))
        td = td[shuffle]
        lab = lab[shuffle]

        print("Shuffled List")
        print("Starting SVM")

        svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
        svm.setType(cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC)
        # Exponential Chi2 kernel, similar to the RBF kernel: K(xi,xj)=e−γχ2(xi,xj),χ2(xi,xj)=(xi−xj)2/(xi+xj),γ>0.
        svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_CHI2)
        svm.setTermCriteria((cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6))
        svm.setGamma(5.383)
        svm.setC(2.67)
        print("Starting Training")

        svm.train(td, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, lab)

        print("Saving to .yml")

        svm.save(os.path.join(self.base_path, "svm_model.yml"))
```

I then use that SVM model to try and predict if an image is a 1 (Bad Image) or a 0 (Good Image). With the help of the kernel and edge detection I used in my first attempt:

```
    def predict(self):
        svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load("./svm_model.yml")

        for file in self.files:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.base_path, "1_Frames", os.path.basename(file)))
            print(f"Starting predict on {file}")
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
            while cap.isOpened():
                success, image = cap.read(1)
                if success:
                    img = cv2.resize(image, self.winSize, interpolation=cv2.CV_32F)
                    test_data = self.hog.compute(img)
                    test_data = cv2.normalize(test_data, None)
                    test_data = np.float32(test_data)
                    test_data = np.transpose(test_data)

                    if not np.any(test_data):
                        print("Invalid Dimension")
                        success, image = cap.read(1)
                        print(f"New Frame {success}")
                    else:
                        response = svm.predict(test_data)[1]
                        if response == 1:
                            gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=image, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                            sharpen_kernel = np.array([[.4, .4], [-2.25, -2.25], [.4, .4]])
                            sharpen = cv2.filter2D(src=gray, ddepth=-1, kernel=sharpen_kernel)
                            sharpe = sharpen + 128

                            canny = cv2.Canny(image=sharpe, threshold1=245, threshold2=255, edges=1, apertureSize=3, L2gradient=True)
                            white = np.where(canny != [0])
                            if not len(white[0]) == 0:
                                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(self.base_path, '1_Frames', os.path.basename(file), f'found_{self.x}.jpg'), image)
                                success, image = cap.read(1)
                                self.x += 1
                            else:
                                success, image = cap.read(1)
                                pass
                        else:
                            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(self.base_path, '0_Frames', f'found_{self.y}.jpg'), image)
                            success, image = cap.read(1)
                            self.y += 1
                else:
                    break

            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This method seems to work well, but I am still open to any further ideas of suggestions. I posted this new update in hopes it may assist someone else looking for suggestions on how to detect issues in images.

Comment: what exactly do you call "pixelation"? it's certainly not a "mosaic" effect for obscuring something because that video contained *none* of that. a screenshot would have been handy, or a video that plays inside google drive webpage. if you mean "glitches" from missing/corrupted data in the stream... you can detect that on the stream level. transport streams (.ts) contain a bunch of error checking and sequence numbers. only after that should you even attempt to detect glitches in the decoded video frames themselves.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have updated my question with more detail regarding what I mean by pixelation, and have added screenshots that may help.

Detecting issues with the stream is something I could do, but I am currently using an external camera to record the video. This is because I am recording video from a STB which is connected to a TV via HDMI. Then I am performing processing on that recorded video to detect macro-blocking style issues.

Comment: Presumably you'd localise the "pixelation" you detect to a rectangular region and extract that area to an image of its own to run pytesseract against. Equally presumably, if the image area is corrupted then successful text detection may not be very likely, so you may need a non-OCR way of detecting text - isn't the fact the text is white and covering some area going to be usable to guess there's text?

Comment: these artefacts are fundamentally not distinguishable from true image features. you will have different glitches: bad intra updates (blocks pop up that don't look like their surroundings), and bad motion updates (stuff moves wrong or failed to move when it should have). a better approach might be to record the same stream multiple ways, and then compare that (align temporally first). "two out of three" or sth to figure out which stream had glitches.

Comment: @balmy I attempted to use shape detection but was unsuccessful as many other objects have rectangles in the image. Maybe you could provide a sample code of what you were thinking? Also, I was thinking that I could build in some sort of probability equation that would assign a score based on the region the edges were found.
@ChristophRackwitz Not sure I can do that given I am attempting to do this with no-reference to any prior (or parallel) streams. I have attempted to use ```cv2.quality.QualityBRISQUE_compute()```, but with no success.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend fixing the title of your question because it is a mismatch to the actual question.